# Replace all occurrences of the substring on HTML page without replaceAll and keep case as original

Tags: javascript, html, replace, replaceall, regexp-replace

I'm trying to replace all occurrences of the substring given from input without using `replaceAll` and keep case as original match. That's what I have now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input class="searchInput" type="text">
    <p id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum adipisci a quia quas reiciendis. Consectetur excepturi iusto, corporis sapiente cupiditate quae sequi nobis voluptatibus ullam cum suscipit quibusdam quo maiores.</p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var searchInput = document.querySelector('.searchInput')
        var text = document.querySelector('#text')
        function displayMatches(e) {
            var regex = new RegExp(e.target.value, 'ig')
            var response = text.innerText.replace(regex, function(match) {
                return text.innerText.split(regex).join("<span style='background-color: yellow;'>" + match + "</span>")
            })
            text.innerHTML = response
        }
        searchInput.addEventListener('change', displayMatches)
        searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', displayMatches)
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't work as expected. I achieved the what I want using the `replaceAll` like this:

```
var searchInput = document.querySelector('.searchInput')
var text = document.querySelector('#text')
function displayMatches(e) {
    var regex = new RegExp(e.target.value, 'ig')
    var response = text.innerText.replaceAll(regex, function(match) {
        return "<span style='background-color: yellow;'>" + match + "</span>"
    })
    text.innerHTML = response
}
searchInput.addEventListener('change', displayMatches)
searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', displayMatches)
```

But I wonder if it's possible to achieve without `replaceAll` [for cross-browser reasons](https://caniuse.com/?search=replaceAll) with `split 'n join` for example or something else.

**EDIT:**

It works somehow with `replace`: https://jsfiddle.net/21txy05u/

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I could understand I made this little script check it out:
What I do is show the first match in yellow and the rest in red
for some reason when they try to search for ".." or more the code breaks but the rest works

```js
function search(){
  let search=document.querySelector("#search").value
  let text=document.querySelector("#text")
  text.innerHTML=text.innerText
  let reg=new RegExp(((search.indexOf(".")>-1)?"\\"+search:search),"ig")
  let aux=text.innerText.split(reg)
  if(aux.length>1){
     text.innerHTML=aux[0]+"<span style='background-color: yellow;'>" +search+ "</span>"+aux.splice(1).join("<span style='background-color: red;color:white;'>" +search+ "</span>")
  }
 
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" id="search" onkeyup="search()">
<p id="text">
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda vero nobis impedit, suscipit ab voluptates iste voluptas tempora! Tenetur enim, unde corporis cupiditate quisquam doloribus molestiae. Iste ipsam nihil porro?
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `String:replace` which has the same percentage of compatibility as `String:split`